# Bash: How do I transform this text to fit my needs?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I'm writing a Bash script where I need to transform a bunch of lines that look like the following:

```
/* 100 */ "Continue",
/* 101 */ "Switching Protocols",
# ...
```

to this:

```
case 100: return "Continue";
case 101: return "Switching Protocols";
# ...
```

How would I do this using the command-line tools? The reason I'm asking is because I'm not really sure how to 'capture' variables (100, "Continue") with regex + sed/grep and transform them into new lines of text.

If you're interested, here is a gist of the full output (note that some lines don't have commas at the end): https://gist.github.com/aa5d19778844334b3ecd7d98cca67301

Thanks!

EDIT by @EdMorton

The actual 4 different input styles shown in the linked file plus one that's not present but could happen are:

```
/* 101 */ "Switching Protocols",
/* 425 */ null,
/* 426 */ "Upgrade Required", // RFC 2817
/* 507 */ "Insufficient Storage"
/* 999 */ "Made Up But Could Happen" // RFC 9999
```

Please provide the expected output below for all of the above:

```
case 101: return "Switching Protocols";
case 425: ?
case 426: ?
case 507: return "Insufficient Storage";
case 999: ?
```

If you can have C-style comments at the end, e.g. `/* 426 */ "Upgrade Required", /* RFC 2817 */`, then include cases to cover that too.

Comment: Your question is missing important variations in your input data. A solution for what you've posted may not work for what you haven't posted, and we'd just be guessing what you want output for the lines that follow the styles you haven't shown us. I edited your question to include the 4 different styles found in your linked file that you need to consider when writing a tool to parse that file. Please complete the edit to show the expected output given THAT input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with simple `sed` substitutions and GNU sed, like:

```
sed -r 's+/\*+case+g; s+\s*\*/\s*+: return +g; s+(,\s*)?(//.*)?$+;\2+g' yourfile
```

The  `sed` `s` commands use `+` as separator (usually `/` is used but the comments have `/` too). The `*` needs escaping and becomes `\*`.

The funny `\s*\*/\s*` means: optional whitespaces `\s*` followed by a star (escaped it becomes `\*`) followed by `/` and again optional whitespaces `\s*`.

Comment: That's pretty clever.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do it so that I get `case 101: return` instead of `case 101 :return`?

Comment: The posted sample input/output in the question does not adequately represent the OPs actual data. For example he has a line `/* 426 */ "Upgrade Required", // RFC 2817` which, if you ran your script on it would append the terminating semi-colon to the end of the comment instead of putting it before the comment (or removing the comment). We need more info from the OP to know how to handle his **actual** input formats.

Comment: @EdMorton  My first idea was: no need for sed, use the editor and replace '/*' with 'case', and '*/' with ' return: ' and ',' at line end with ';'. That idea expressed in sed was short and straight forward. Now it has become a real mess.

Comment: Right and we don't even know what the OP wants done with some of the cases. e.g. does `null` in the input need to get quotes added so it becomes `"null"` in the output? idk and the OP has fallen silent...

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed 's%/\* \([0-9]*\) \*/ \([^,]*\).*%case \1: return \2;%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r 's/[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*(".*").*/case \1: return \2;/' file
case 100: return "Continue";
case 101: return "Switching Protocols";
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming this the for the block of a switch statement, this will work with the updated input styles.

```
$ sed -r 's_/\*_case_;s_ \*/_: return_;s_("[^"]*")[^;]?_\1;_;s_,$_;_' file          

case 101: return "Switching Protocols";
case 425: return null;
case 426: return "Upgrade Required"; // RFC 2817
case 507: return "Insufficient Storage";
case 999: return "Made Up But Could Happen";// RFC 9999
```

handles missing commas at the end as well.  Obviously if null is not an acceptable value you have to replace it with a default value.